# UFT 12.52 / VBScript - Test object exist, is visible and enabled before take an action

Tags: hp-uft, vbscript

I'm automating tests using UFT 12.52 for an application.

I captured the objects for a repository and then started to create a sequence of actions on the objects.

However, there is a frequent problem. Before calling an action on an object it needs to exist, be visible, and in some cases be enabled (e.g. textboxes).

To solve this problem I tried testing if the object exists, and is visible (and enabled, if applicable), before the call to any action on the object. If those  are true, then make a action with the object. Testing these properties of the object is done until a timeout has been exceeded. If the timeout is exceeded an exception should be thrown.

I developed the code below, but the result is very unstable behavior:

- Non-recognition of the current object being tested
- No recognition of the parent object
- UFT starts to test an object of the 2nd line, before executing the
  action on the object of the 1st line ...

I have the following questions:

- Is there a UFT/VBScript solution that solves this problem?
- Are there problems in my algorithm?

Here is my code:

```
Function test() 
    clickObj SwfWindow("<parent object name 1 >").SwfButton("<child object name 1>"), true  
    clickObj SwfWindow("<parent object name 2 >").SwfButton("<child object name 2>"), false
End Function

Function clickObj(obj, isEnabled)   
    If (prepareObj(obj, isEnabled) = true) Then     
        obj.Click       
    Else        
        Err.Raise 424 'Error 424 = "Object required"        
    End if  
End Function

Function prepareObj(obj, isEnabled) 
    If isEnabled = true Then        
        If ((testObjProperty(obj,"exist") = true) And (testObjProperty(obj,"visible") = true) And (testObjProperty(obj,"enabled") = true)) Then     
            prepareObj = true   
        else            
            prepareObj = false          
        End If      
    Else    
        If ((testObjProperty(obj,"exist") = true) And (testObjProperty(obj,"visible") = true)) Then     
            prepareObj = true                   
        else            
            prepareObj = false          
        End If  
    End If          
End Function

Function testObjProperty(obj, propertyName) 
    Dim startTime : startTime = Timer
    Dim elapsedTime : elapsedTime = 0
    Dim propertyOk : propertyOk = false
    Dim timeout : timeout = 45

    Do      
        Select Case propertyName            
            Case "exist"                
                propertyOk = obj.Exist(1)                           
            Case "visible"              
                propertyOk = obj.GetROProperty("visible")                           
            Case "enabled"              
                propertyOk = obj.GetROProperty("enabled")                                       
        End Select

        If propertyOk = true Then           
            testObjProperty = true                                  
            Exit Function
        Else            
            elapsedTime = Timer - startTime                         
        End If              
    Loop While timeout > elapsedTime

    testObjProperty = false         
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic error in this line of code:

```
If ((testObjProperty(obj,"exist") = true) And (testObjProperty(obj,"visible") = true) And (testObjProperty(obj,"enabled") = true)) Then
```

There is a logic statement `A And B And C`, and **VBScript is computing each parameter A, B, C; regardless of the value of A, B and C**, even if A and B is `False`, C is still evaluated.

If the first statement `(testObjProperty(obj,"exist") = true)` is `False`, VBScript is still going to execute the second statement `(testObjProperty(obj,"visible") = true)` and it will definitely fail here one day because the object may not exist.

You should perform the check below (pseudo-code):

```
If Object.Exist Then
    If Object.Visible And Object.Enabled Then
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
Else
    ...
End If
```